# How to detect if point lies segment

Tags: c, geometry, computational-geometry

Currently I can detect whether the point belongs to a line segment with the following code:

```
uint8_t point_lies_onSegment(const POINT2D *point, const POINT2D *linea, const POINT2D *lineb) {
double slope, intercept;
  double px, py;
  double left, top, right, bottom; // Bounding Box For Line Segment
  double dx, dy;

px = point->x;
py = point->y;

dx = lineb->x - linea->x;
dy = lineb->y - linea->y;

  slope = dy / dx;
  // y = mx + c
  // intercept c = y - mx
  intercept = linea->y - slope * linea->x; // which is same as y2 - slope * x2

  // For Bounding Box
  if(linea->x < lineb->x) {
    left = linea->x;
    right = lineb->x;
  } else {
    left = lineb->x;
    right = linea->x;
  }
  if(linea->y < lineb->y) {
    top = linea->y;
    bottom = lineb->y;
  } else {
    top = linea->y;
    bottom = lineb->y;
  }

  //"Equation of the line: %.2f X %c %.2f\n", slope, ((intercept < 0) ? ' ' : '+'), intercept;

  if( slope * px + intercept > (py - FP_TOLERANCE) &&
    slope * px + intercept < (py + FP_TOLERANCE)) {
      if( px >= left && px <= right && 
          py >= top && py <= bottom ) {
            return VG_TRUE;
      }
      else
        return VG_FALSE;
  }
  else
    return VG_FALSE;
}
```

But if the line is vertical it does not work as expected. 
Eg:

line segment = (10, 10) - (10, 30)
point = (10, 20)

This return FALSE.

How to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the line is vertical, you need to check the x-coordinate of the point in question. If the x-coord of the point is the same as the x-coord for the vertical line segment - then check to see if the y-coord of the point is between the y-coords of the vertical line segment.

Comment: I add the following code: 
 if(FP_EQUALS(dx, 0.0)) {
  if(py <= lineb->y && py >= linea->y)
   return VG_TRUE;
  else
   return VG_FALSE;
 } and it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A vertical line is going to cause your program to divide by zero.  I'm surprised you get any output at all - I'd have expected it just to crash.  Since it's not crashing, you're likely getting `NaN` into `slope`, which causes the rest of your problems.  You're probably going to want to use a different algorithm than you're currently using - something that doesn't require you to calculate the slope, for example.

Comment: Which different algorithm?

Comment: kalaero suggests one in his answer, there are plenty of others. I'm sure if you google a bit you'll turn something up.